# using bash commands in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I never used bash with jupyter notebook. For some project, I need to use bash with python but it's giving me errors. I have installed bash kernel also.

```
PATH="/Downloads/dogscats/"
!ls {PATH}
```

> 'ls' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: `{PATH}` isn't really a valid Bash expression. Perhaps you mean `${PATH}` (where however the braces aren't really useful or necessary)? (Not too familiar with Jupyter though.)

Comment: using windows 8.1

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to use bash commands in Jupyter Notebook, even on Windows systems, as long as Jupyter is launched from a bash-compliant command line such as Git Bash (MingW64). As shown in the OP's code example, the bash command must be prepended by an exclamation mark (`!`).

The real key, however, is launching from [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) or possibly [Ubuntu on Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#0) .

I'm running windows 10 Pro with Python installed via Anaconda, and the following code works when I launch Jupyter via Git Bash, but does not when I launch from the Anaconda prompt.

```
>>> !ls
database.sqlite
Weather Data Clustering using k-Means.ipynb

>>>!pip show lxml | grep Version
Version: 4.1.0
```

Comment: It seems to depend on the core ("kernel") supporting the `!`. With Python it works but not say with the JavaScript core (IJavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Installing [Git Bash for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) did it to me. After that, run the jupyter notebook from there.