# cv2.VideoCapture not working in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am currently trying to do some video classification and am using anaconda along with jupyter notebook to do my training of data. However, I am encountering an error in jupyter notebook where I can't read in my video frames using cv2.VideoCapture but somehow it does work in my conda environment's terminal.

This is my file structure,
[image: This is my file structure]

This is the error I'm currently encountering,
[image: This is the error I'm currently encountering]

Terminal in the same anaconda environment works fine,
[image: Terminal in the same anaconda environment works fine]

I did read somewhere that it might be due to an issue with conda and ffmepg but I have tried many solutions suggested by others to solve that issue including downloading opencv from opencv.org itself and setting the environment path variables instead of using conda install but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: This question is old but (1) there's an extra leading slash in the jupyter notebook version (assuming that it's the cause, it's a typo-question and should be closed) and (2) always provide the code in text form (image is optional).

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I noticed that you are not using the same filename in your two tests. I was stuck at the same point, till I realized the path and filename was not the same between my "terminal test" and the jupyter notebook test.
I confirmed jupyter could access the file.

Windows attribute test:

```
!attrib data/TownCentreXVID.avi
```

Bash file test. See [using bash commands in jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48539900/using-bash-commands-in-jupyter-notebook) for details:

```
!file data/TownCentreXVID.avi
```

Then tried again, and had no issues getting the same results from jupyter.
[image: confirm file access]

[image: read first image]

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV in Python enables you to grab frames from the webcam/ or from a video file (like in your case) as Numpy array, modify it and then display it using OpenCV's cv2.imshow(). To do this OpenCV will create a window and push the frames there. However, this will not work in a IPython notebook.

To display in the jupyter notebook or any other IPython notebook, you will have to use the function

```
IPython.display.Image(data)
```

and not OpenCV's imshow().

Here is a chunk of code you can use:

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

d = IPython.display.display("", display_id=1)
d2 = IPython.display.display("", display_id=2)
while True:
    try:
        t1 = time.time()
        frame = get_frame(cam)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        im = array_to_image(frame)

        d.update(im)

        t2 = time.time()

        s = f"""{int(1/(t2-t1))} FPS"""
        d2.update( IPython.display.HTML(s) )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print()
        cam.release()
        IPython.display.clear_output()
        print ("Stream stopped")
        break


def get_frame(cam):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cam.read()

    #flip image for natural viewing
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    return frame
#Use 'jpeg' instead of 'png' (~5 times faster)
def array_to_image(a, fmt='jpeg'):
    #Create binary stream object
    f = BytesIO()

    #Convert array to binary stream object
    PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)

    return IPython.display.Image(data=f.getvalue())
```

Comment: Well, after using your code and testing around abit, it seems that if I use cv2.VideoCapture(0) to get frames from my webcam, cap.isOpened() returns True even without using IPython.display.

However, I am trying to train my model using the UCF101 dataset, hence, I need to load videos from my local disk and it seems that it isn't working.